# How do I ask for follow up after initial discussion with recruiter?

Tags: recruitment, internship, follow-up

I am a first year undergraduate student, and recently a recruiter at a mid-sized startup contacted me asking if I'd like to meet one of their senior software engineers to discuss opportunities at the startup.

As I am looking for a summer internship, I said yes and met him. We chatted for about 20 minutes about the startup and my resume, and he said it was "impressive". He told me to send my resume and transcript over so that he could "forward them to the right people and follow up from there". It's been 2 weeks since and I haven't heard back from them.

Should I email him asking for a follow-up and if so how should the email look like?

Comment: Should I email him asking for a follow-up = yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should follow up. Two weeks is plenty of wait

"Hi, I'm really excited about the opportunity of an internship at XYZ. Did you had a chance yet to look at the materials that I sent you on . I'm really interested in making this work, so please let me know what else I can do to aid with the process"

something along those lines. Don't just copy this, make sure it sounds like you.

Try again after another week. If you still don't hear anything after a second attempt, than it's dead and time to move on. In the meantime it may be worth looking at other opportunities in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should follow up.

you can write something as @Hilmar suggested, or take a different approach like "i have been researching about your company and came across this article/blog post, and it has reinforced my interest in interning at this firm. If the position is already closed, i would appreciate a confirmation so I can pursue other options."

Or if you have other opportunities available, it would be good to sneak in a line about it, so that it prompts these guys to make a decision.